# How to prove order of equation using Big-Oh notation?

Tags: asymptotics

How can I prove this order equation using Big-Oh notation?
$$O(3n^3+2n^2+5) = n^3$$

Comment: It is not a linear equation. What is the *rank* of this equation.

Comment: It is also not an equation. There needs to be an equals sign for something to be an equation.

Comment: the question is edited; I am asking the prove of order. fyi @Bernard and Thomas Andrews

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (3n^3+2n^2+5)/n^3 = 3 \ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $n^{3} = O(3n^{3} + 2n^{2} + 5)$ (with "as $n \to \infty$" when speaking of asymptotics) means that there is some $M > 0$ such that $$n^{3} \leq M(3n^{3} + 2n^{2} + 5)$$
for large $n$.
But, since
$$\frac{n^{3}}{3n^{3} + 2n^{2} + 5} = \frac{1}{3 + \dfrac{2}{n} + \dfrac{5}{n^{3}}} < 1$$
for all $n \geq 1,$
the equation under consideration holds.

Comment: Please also note that the equal sign linking the big O is simply a shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the big-O, the equation reads as $"$there are constants $N$ and $C$ such that

$$\forall n\ge N:n^3\le C(3n^3+2n^2+5)."$$

Clearly, $N=C=1$ make it true.